# Use static variable in static function

Tags: php, oop, static, static-variables

How do I reference a static variable from within a static function in the same class?

I am trying:

```
class SQL {

public static $partsNetTotalPounds = '...';

public static function margin()
  {
    return '('.$this->partsNetTotalPounds...
  }
}
```

Ofcourse this does not work because I haven't instantiated the object SQL.

How can this be done?

Comment: two ways either `SQL::$partsNetTotalPounds` or `self::$partsNetTotalPounds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static function margin()
  {
    return "(" . self::$partsNetTotalPounds ;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about that keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `self` keyword

```
self::$partsNetTotalPounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other people have pointed out use the `self` keyword:
`self::$partsNetTotalPounds`.

If the value of the `$partsNetTotalPounds` is all you need you don't need to access it through the `margin` method, by the way.  Instead you can access it via `SQL::$partsNetTotalPounds`.

`$this` is used to access properties of an instance so it does not apply in this case.